# How to prevent race condition in online hotel booking

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

I am writing a hotel booking software using PHP and MySQL. I am pretty much done with it but I ran into a race condition problem. For example there is only one standard room left and when 2 guests both select it it shows available to both of them. I tried fixing it by checking the room again when the guest clicks confirm before payment but that still has issues. I also tried making the room status to pending when whoever clicks the confirm first but I can't figure out how to change it back to available if the guest decides not to pay or just closes the browser. I searched SO for answers but I didn't really find a definitive answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Most sites give users a timebombed lock on the reservation/ticket/etc.  In other words, they set an n-minute timer or whatnot, and if the transaction isn't finished in those n-minutes, it's released back to the general pool.

Comment: how can i go about implementing that

Comment: When, anyone books room, Keep session locked for that room for few minutes (7min), show same timer to end-user that if he wont book ticket in X minutes of time, his booking session will be released.  In this time, one would successfully go thru transaction process and other required thing. cronjob would be good idea to automate this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution is to add two columns to a table in the database. One column is the session ID or user ID or whatever of the user that is being offered the room. The second column is a timestamp indicating when that offer will expire.

Then, in your app, only show rooms that have an expired timestamp in the hold column.  (Set the initial timestamp to 0 so that it starts out expired.) When a room is selected, check the column again. If there's an unexpired timestamp there, the user gets a "sorry, you were too slow" message. Otherwise, put a timestamp there for 15 minutes into the future or whatever, and proceed.

You see this on travel sites and ticket-purchasing sites a lot where it says something like "We're holding these seats for you for another 14 minutes. Please complete the transaction by then or it will be released blah blah blah."

Comment: I love you Trott! That is exactly what I needed. All I have to do is keep checking that timestamp. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would also go with the pending state. You could save the state together with the session id of this user and have a cronjob that deletes all pending states that have expired session ids associated to them.